# Will QTimer timeout signal be sent after stop() is called?

Tags: c++, qt, qtimer

I am working on Qt 5.5 / 4.8 now. I worry about whether `timeout()` signal could be (occasionally）sent after the timer is explicitly stopped by calling `stop()` on that instance?

I hope the `timeout()` signal will be sent just between `start()` and `stop()`, but is that the truth?

My situation is: the `start()` and `stop()` are both called in main thread, and the `timeout()` signal is connect as directly connection. (I know that queued connection cannot guarantee the above statement.)

Comment: Of course not )

Comment: No signal will be sent after `stop()`. However, For `Qt::CoarseTimer` and `Qt::VeryCoarseTimer` types, `QTimer` may wake up earlier than expected

Comment: @sp2danny Thank you guys very much! Another similar question is: for a button on a widget: if there is a chance that the clicked() slot is deliveried (processed) after the widget (contains that button) is hided by calling hide()? For instance, widget.hide() gets called in a timer's timeout() slot, and user clicks the button just at the same time timeout() is called. Is there a chance that the button's clicked() slot get called after timer's timeout() slot()?

Comment: @guanboshen I suggest you to publish the second question as a new post: SO explicitly encourages users to do so in order to keep well documented questions.

Comment: @cbuchart Thank you for your suggestion. I will post another question for that.

Answer (score 4):

Quick answer: **no**, it won't be called on most of the cases, but there is at least one exception.

A situation when it may be called is if you have used [queued connections](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum). Here you may get the associated slots to be called *after* you've stopped if, for example, the `QTimer::timeout` signal happens to be emitted *before* stopping the timer.

In the case above slots are queued (but not necessarily called), so it may happen that you call `QTimer::stop` before slots are actually invoked.

If you use queued connections you can check for [`QTimer::isActive()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#isActive) at the beginning of the slot (you'll need some way to access the timer of course, maybe as a member of the class).